# Difference between pandas objects (index, ndarray, etc) and datatypes (e.g. bool, int, float)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning pandas and have a pretty basic question. I get that pandas introduces a lot of different new objects based on numpy arrays (like index and numpy array), but how are these 'objects' that exist in pandas different from pandas datatypes I'm learning like np.bool, int, float, datetime64?

If objects like pandas index's are lego blocks that allow us to do things in pandas, what are these datatypes considered? are datatypes also pandas objects?

Comment: Im not really following. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: i guess another way to ask is, what is a datatype in pandas (i.e. np.datetime64 or np.float)? how is this different from other pandas objects like pandas.core.indexes.base.Index? or are datatypes and Index objects both objects, its just that datatypes are on a smaller (more atomic) level of building block?

Comment: like, is a series or ndarray OBJECTS that are made up of different datatype objects? thanks

Comment: A datatype is an instruction to numpy on how to allocate memory for the data that the array contains (note that it's a numpy object, not a pandas one). The index is an attribute of the pandas DataFrame object created in python.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting question (your last comment). Actually, I'm not sure how to answer that strictly.

Comment: @roganjosh thank you regardless!

Comment: *Everything* is an object in Python. `pandas` is a library with custom container objects, notably, the `pd.Series` and the `pd.DataFrame`. These are based on `numpy` objects, the `numpy.ndarray`. All of them require a datatype, a "dtype", which basically describe the underlying structure of the array memory layout, and how each individual item is interpreted. The array objects are not "made up of" the dtype objects,

Answer (score 1):

Pandas objects `DataFrame`, `Index` and `Series` provide the high level data structure.

`DataFrame` is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dictionary of `Series` objects.

`Index` encapsulates the row and column labels.

`Series` encapsulates a one-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` containing the column data, row labels and the column label.

See [Pandas DataFrame data structure](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/pandas-dataframe/) for details.

---

Each column data is a `numpy.ndarray` object of a specific *numpy data type* like bool (`numpy.bool_`), int (`numpy.int32`, `numpy.int64`, etc.), float (`numpy.float32`, `numpy.float64`, etc.) and others. NumPy supports a much greater variety of numerical types than Python.

See [Data types in Python, Numpy and Pandas](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/data-types-python-numpy-pandas/) for details.